# Configuring evdev conf for middle mouse button emulation

Tags: xorg, mouse

I am trying to edit my evdev configuration to emulate middle mouse button with both clicking both left and right mouse button simultaneously. This is what I appended to `/etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/10-evdev.conf` and then I restarted my machine. But it does not work. Can you see what I do wrong?

```
Section "InputClass"
    Identifier "Logitech Mouse"
    MatchProduct "USB-PS/2 Optical Mouse"
    MatchVendor "Logitech"
    Option "Evdev Middle Button Emulation" "true"
EndSection
```

This is the output of xinput list:

```
⎡ Virtual core pointer                      id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ Logitech USB-PS/2 Optical Mouse           id=9    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ AKKO AKKO 3084BT                          id=11   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ PS/2 Generic Mouse                        id=14   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad                id=15   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                     id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Sleep Button                              id=8    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ AKKO AKKO 3084BT                          id=10   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ HP HD Webcam [Fixed]                      id=12   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ AT Translated Set 2 keyboard              id=13   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ HP Wireless hotkeys                       id=16   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ HP WMI hotkeys                            id=17   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ ACPI Virtual Keyboard Device              id=18   [slave  keyboard (3)]
```

Comment: Just to be sure: You are using X-server and not Wayland, are you?

Comment: Yes, also `sudo xinput set-prop 9 "Evdev Middle Button Emulation" 1` will do what I want to achieve, but I don't want to run that manually every time I start-up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your approach to configure it via xorg.conf.d is absolute correct.
I am not sure about my solution, but it may be worth a try:

```
Identifier "evdev pointer catchall"
MatchIsPointer "on"
MatchDevicePath "/dev/input/event*"
Driver "evdev"
```

Add/replace in your "Input class" section the code above. (Change Identifier, add the rest)
Logitech can sometimes be a little different, but I had success with a problem using these parameters.

Does your Xorg.log.0 give any clues about your script ?

If everything fails you may create an systemd service that executes your command: (This is not a solution, but a workaround):

```
[Unit]
Description="Middle mouse emulation

[Service]
Type=simple
ExecStart= xinput set-prop 9 "Evdev Middle Button Emulation" 1

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Enable the service and it should run the next time you start...

Comment: Well, the id is not always 9, so it is not that simple.

Comment: Xorg.log.0 gives `evdev: Logitech USB-PS/2 Optical Mouse: Unable to query fd: Inappropriate ioctl for device`

Comment: What happens if you change the conf file? You'll tell X to look somewhere else... As I said: it's a workaround (and not a very good one obviously ;-) See [here](https://www.spinics.net/linux/fedora/fedora-users/msg472142.html) for an ancient problem.

Comment: That's not the problem. The conf file already existed. I just added my portion to it.

Comment: You wrote  `Identifier "Logitech Mouse"`  and I suggested `Identifier "evdev pointer catchall"`. Does it affect your problem?

Comment: The link to the fedora-users email list eventually had the correct solution.

Comment: Glad it helped. Thanks for upvoting

Answer (score 0):

The solution:

Add below to `/etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/10-evdev.conf`

```
Section "InputClass"
      Identifier "middle button emulation class"
      MatchIsPointer "on"        
      MatchDevicePath "/dev/input/event*"
      Option "Emulate3Buttons" "on"
      Driver "evdev"
EndSection
```

From https://www.spinics.net/linux/fedora/fedora-users/msg472142.html

EDIT: On recent machines "Emulate3DButtons has changed to "MiddleEmulation"

From https://forums.freebsd.org/threads/where-to-put-xorgs-emulate3button-these-days.88837/